# Symfony 3.2 buit-in server error after upgrade to PHP 7.4.4

Tags: php, symfony

While upgrading my project developed in Symfony 2.8  to 3.2 on PHP 7.4 i have experienced problems trying to launch the built-in server on console using:

`php app\console server:run`

i receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'ReflectionClass' is not allow
>   ed in C:\wamp\www\projetos\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Comp
>   onent\DependencyInjection\Config\AutowireServiceResource.php on line 58

i think it's a compatibility problem between Symfony packages and PHP 7.4.4 once my project was working on PHP 7.0 before upgrade.

Thanks in advance any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Symfony 3.2 is no longer maintained](https://symfony.com/releases), or even recieving security fixes. You should probably roll back your PHP version to one that existed (and was supported) at the time of the last release of 3.2 which was [January 2018](https://symfony.com/releases/3.2)

Comment: Your answer made me think outside of box and i solved upgrade my project to Symfony 3.4 maintained version. After some adjustments it has worked perfectly. Thanks Amelia.